# Sortable with multiple lists return to first list

Tags: jquery, html, list, jquery-ui

I have multiple lists. Each list and all the items have the same class.

Example:

```
<ul class="cat_1">
    <li class="cat_1">Item1</li>
    <li class="cat_1">Item2</li>
    <li class="cat_1">Item2</li>
</ul>

<ul class="cat_2">
    <li class="cat_2">Item1</li>
    <li class="cat_2">Item2</li>
    <li class="cat_2">Item2</li>
</ul>
```

I have also an empty list

```
<ul></ul>
```

The items of the list can be dropped into the empty list. This is limited to 3-items (TOP 3). This is already done.

But I want it also possible to remove them again from the TOP 3 and add it again to the correct list (automatic). So I added a delete-"button" (span) to every li who is dropped in the top3-list:

```
$( "#top3" ).sortable({
    receive: function( event, ui ) {
        $(ui.item).append("<span class='removeItem' onclick='removeTest(this)'>X</span>");
    }
});
```

If I click on the span, I get the "X"..
But how can I get the parent (the li with the class (like cat_1/cat_2)?

And how can I add it again to the correct list (ul with cat_1-class or cat_2-class?

> I also tried it with another workflow, but that seems not to be a good way of
>   doing it (to much user interaction necessary): When dropped back to a
>   list (not TOP3 but cat_1 or cat_2), I checked the class. If class was
>   ok, I did nothing. Otherwise I removed the li. But I couldn't add the
>   li (object) to the correct list... (I tried with .append() &
>   .appendTo()).

Comment: example -- http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists

Comment: Sortable isn't a problem. It's an additional feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly clear on what you're wanting to do. A Fiddle showing what you have so far might be helpful.

However, your removeTest method should probably look something like this:

```
function removeTest(span){
    var elem = $(span).parent();
    var elemClass = elem.attr("class");
    $('ul.' + elemClass).append(elem);
    $('#top3').remove(elem);
}
```

Comment: So easy.. Just $(span) to get the element.. I was trying to find the id attribute of the object..

Comment: You gotta love jQuery!